# Why Laravel updateOrCreate() & upsert() both need argument to uniquely identify records?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Both `updateOrCreate()` & `upsert()` do the same thing, insert or update, I think they both generate SQL `INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY`. So I feel providing argument to uniquely identify records seems unnecessary.

Why do they need ["the second argument lists the column(s) that uniquely identify records within the associated table."](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts) ?

The reason I can think of maybe in some case they do not generate the sql `INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY` so they may need arguments to uniquely identify records? But is this the case ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: mysql, 5.6 or 5.7 in different products

Comment: Have you tried debugging how the queries look like? Otherwise, if you want to know why the Laravel developers wrote their methods like that, why not ask them?

Comment: `INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY` needs the provided values to cause duplicate violation. I.e. (a) at least one unique index must exist in the table (b) the value(s) for all column(s) used in at least one unique index must be provided. Hence these values (in complex) identifies the row uniquely.

Comment: *I think they both generate SQL INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY.* You may enable General Log temporarily and look what queries are generated by these methods.

Comment: I think so, hence the question. The DB schema can check duplicate violation we really don't need to provide the arguments

Comment: @NicoHaase I check the code and it confirms my doubt, check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The updateOrCreate method will attempt to find a one record matching the constraints passed as the first parameter and if a the record is found then **it will update the match with the attributes passed as the second parameter**

If no matching record is found a **it will be create record with both the constraints passed as the first parameter and the attributes passed as the second parameter**.

Comment: Do you mean that `updateOrCreate` causes the execution of 2 separate queries - first is SELECT, and second is UPDATE or INSERT depends on the result of first SELECT?

Comment: yes two queries

Comment: @mahmoudmagdy you were right about updateOrCreate uses 2 clauses.

Answer (score 0):

I check Laravel source and it confirms my doubt, for `upsert()`, refer to https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Query/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php#L164

It generates sql `insert on duplicate key update` **but the $uniqueBy argument is not used at all!** （It shouldn't）

```
public function compileUpsert(Builder $query, array $values, array $uniqueBy, array $update)
{
    $sql = $this->compileInsert($query, $values).' on duplicate key update ';

    $columns = collect($update)->map(function ($value, $key) {
        return is_numeric($key)
            ? $this->wrap($value).' = values('.$this->wrap($value).')'
            : $this->wrap($key).' = '.$this->parameter($value);
    })->implode(', ');

    return $sql.$columns;
}
```

For `updateOrCreate()` it actually does **NOT** generate `insert on duplicate key update` but **TWO** sql clauses!!

https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Builder.php#L469

```
public function updateOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])
{
    return tap($this->firstOrNew($attributes), function ($instance) use ($values) {
        $instance->fill($values)->save();
    });
}
```

It is not easy to see the generated sql clause here but checking log, it is 2 clauses, one `insert into` and one `update`